# Hateaos Link relation name not accepting more than one colon (:)

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, spring-hateoas, hateoas

When we use hateoas API to create rest API link, I am not able to provide link relation name with more than one colon (:).

```
import org.springframework.hateoas.Link;
import org.springframework.hateoas.server.mvc.WebMvcLinkBuilder;

 WebMvcLinkBuilder.linkTo(myResource.class)
                .withRel("x:y:z");
```

Provided link relation with **"x:y:z"** but it is taking relation name only up to **"x:y"**.

sample response:

```
"_links": {
    "x:y": {
        "href": "<rest api link>"
    }
}
```

Is there any way to add link relation with more than one colons. Earlier version it is working fine but after migrating to Spring HATEOAS 1.0 we are getting tihis issue.